# how to use `amp;` & `gt;` commands in linux-shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I downloaded a Bash script from Internet.
However, when I try to run it, it fails because of the `&amp;&amp;` commands and prints the following error message:

> No command 'amp' found

What is `amp` ?
What is `gt` ?
What do they do?

Comment: Is the script secret?  It might be.  But the documentation isn't.  Did you try `info bash`?

Comment: `&amp;&amp;` is html-stuff. that translates to `&`. Do a search and replace.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect this has undergone an HTML entity translation. You want to reverse this e.g.

```
&amp; becomes &
```

and

```
&gt; becomes >
```

So (for example)

```
cd /dir &amp;&amp; ls &gt; filename
```

would become

```
cd /dir && ls > filename
```

Answer (score 2):

in other word, `&amp;` is the character reference for "An ampersand". While `gt`  is simply we call it as (greater than).

Answer (score 1):

`&amp` and `&gt` are html escape codes for `&` and `>` respectively.

Either you have downloaded a script that has been htmlized, or you've accidentally downloaded a webpage with the script on.

Check the top line of the file. if it starts with something like `#!/usr/bin/bash` then it's the former and you just need to reverse the changes. If it has something like a `<html>` tag as the start, then you've downloaded the webpage - go back to where you got it and look for something like a 'raw' link